# XPath, two selecting conditions with "and"?

Tags: xml, xpath, selection

Here is my XPath selection:

```
/document/transport/receiver[regcode='70007'] | 
/document/metaxml/LetterMetaData[Type='bill']
```

But this does not fit for my needs. What I actually want, that I can tell with XPath that, if regcode='70007' and Type='bill' then do the action. As I understand then | (pipe) means OR in XPath.

Is there a way for making XPath so that it would check both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/document[
   transport/receiver[regcode='70007'] 
 and 
   metaxml/LetterMetaData[Type='bill']
]
```